# snapshot with CCRenderTexture returns 320x480 image and NOT 640x960

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, snapshot

I use this code to make a snapshot of my Cocos2d game on iOs 6:

```
[CCDirector sharedDirector].nextDeltaTimeZero = YES;

CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
CCRenderTexture* rtx;
rtx = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:winSize.width height:winSize.height];

[rtx begin];
[startNode visit];
[rtx end];
```

It works fine. But on iPhone 4 it returns a picture with size 320x480, whereas the screen is 640x960. How can I get it to return a sharper picture (640x960)?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to log winSize in console ?
Does it display 640x960 ?

Do not mistake Screen pixel size and screen point size. Screen size is 640x960 on retina iPhone, but in point, it will always 320*480.

According to documentation, winSize return size in point.
Try this

```
CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector]. winSizeInPixels;
```

Regards

Comment: Winsize = 320x480
WinsizeInPixels = 640x960

If I use your line of code I end up with a blank picture.

If I use a backgroundimage of 640x1136, I get to see a tiny part of it. 

This suggests that using your line of code the screenshot is taken somewhere outside the screen.

Is there a way to set a starting point for taking the screenshot?

Comment: Have you checked this http://www.raywenderlich.com/33266/how-to-create-dynamic-textures-with-ccrendertexture-in-cocos2d-2-x ?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't help me. What am I missing?